# "No route found matching URL" when uploading media using WordpressPCL API

Tags: c#, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I'm using the [WordpressPCL](https://github.com/wp-net/WordPressPCL) to upload media, and it works fine for one Wordpress site. However, for another site, on the same host, with exactly the same code, config, auth plugin, etc., I get the following exception:

```
No route was found matching the URL and request method
```

I can only presume it's something in the .htaccess, wp-config.php or some other plugin interfering with the API.

Any ideas how I might go about debugging this or figuring out what the problem might be?! Is there any sort of verbose logging that could be turned on (e.g., is there any way to wire this up to something like Serilog and see the actual requests etc?). It doesn't look like it from the code I've browsed, but wanted to check.

Things I've checked:

1. I have the JWT REST API plugin installed, and can see all the endpoints when I browse to /wp-json on the domain
2. I have the auth etc set up in the .htaccess
3. I have the token and CORS enabled in the wp-config.php

I've followed the same steps for both sites, but can't for the life of me figure out why it works for one, but not the other! :)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so after more debugging I managed to figure this out. For some reason, if I use https://example.com/wp-json/ it doesn't work. However, if I used https://www.example.com/wp-json/, it works. No idea why the www would make a difference - particularly when I didn't need that on the other site that I tested with, but it works now!